# Is there any form or program that generates prevalence ratio values ​through logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, ratio, prevalence

When performing a binomial or multinomial logistic regression, odds ratio (OR) values ​​are generated. Is there any form or program that generates a prevalence ratio value instead of OR?

Comment: Yes, probratio in epitools will do the trick, probably not implemented for multinomial regression. https://repitools.wordpress.com/2017/04/14/probratio-converting-ors-to-rrs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of estimating the prevalence ratio is with log binomial regression, which can be estimated with any program implementing glm's (generalized linear models). [There are also other options](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fvets.2017.00193/full).

For more details see [glm with log link in binomial family](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485690/glm-with-log-link-in-binomial-family/485715#485715)